# node.js returning a binary stream

Tags: node.js

Can anyone please help me with this node.js problem?

Here's a node.js function to send the value 0.333333 back to client as binary data:

```
app.get('/GetBinaryData', function(req, res)
                               {
                                    var buf = new Buffer(8);

                                    buf[0] = 0x55;
                                    buf[1] = 0x55;
                                    buf[2] = 0x55;
                                    buf[3] = 0x55;
                                    buf[4] = 0x55;
                                    buf[5] = 0x55;
                                    buf[6] = 0xd5;
                                    buf[7] = 0x3f;

                                    res.send(buf);
                               }
   );
```

Back at client, I can get the stream and convert to a double.

Let's say I wanted to return the value of a variable, say

```
var x = 0.432;
```

In a similar way, how could I do this?

My final goal is to return an array of values, say:

var array = [7.1,5.2,13.3,300.4];

Thanks for any help,
Mitch.

Comment: What if you define an array `var ret = []` at the top of the function, then have an iteration that will push multiple buffers into the ret and finally return the ret to the client?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Buffer#writeDouble*()](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_writedoublebe_value_offset_noassert):

```
let buffer = Buffer.alloc(8);
buffer.writeDoubleLE(0.432);

console.log( buffer.toString('hex') ); // d9cef753e3a5db3f
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Mitch.